# Cat 'overturns' my monitor?

Tags: word-usage

I'm wondering what is the correct verb to describe when a someone causes an object like monitor or vase to fall on side from its upright situation? 
Is `overturn` the correct verb for this circumstances?

Comment: The cat *tipped  the monitor over.*

Comment: Or simply "The cat's just knocked it over". "Overturn" sounds a bit formal for describing such a commonplace occurrence, as if the cat had carefully taken the monitor in its paws and carefully turned it on its side.

Comment: overturn "b. To cause to fall over; knock or topple over: bumped the vase and overturned it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**topple**

[From Oxford Dictionaries:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/topple)

> Overbalance or cause to overbalance and fall.

Other common phrases are

**bring down**

[From Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/bring-down)

> to make someone or something move or fall to the ground

and

**tip over**

[from Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tip%20over)

> to fall over or to cause (something) to fall over